# CSS show div when hovering an image

Tags: html, css

I want to use a CSS rollover on a site but when I try to implement the CSS, it crashes the site, I believe it has something to do with the `<div>`. What can I change it to, to keep it from crashing?

jsfiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/ANKwQ/5315/

Comment: What does it mean to you "it crashes the site"?
When adding a `display: block;` to a div, this will make it expand to reach its full size. If it has been placed at the top of the site, everything after it in your DOM will do down. If it makes you lose the focus on your element, this will make the block disappear again and reappear when you focus it. It can go on and on again and make everything "blinking".

Comment: When i add the ccs to the site , the site just goes blank

Comment: It is because you wrote `div { display: none }` which will target all divs on your page

Comment: But if i remove that , the rollover text doesn't work

Comment: It might help to tell you that the site is through wordpress

Comment: It's for a project , when a user scrolls over a picture of a team member a text box pops up below with a bio , but i'm completely stumped by it

Comment: As I said, if you want to display your div containing your picture (and only this div, not all the others that are not related to it), you must add an `id` to it. `<div id="foo"><img src=... /></div>` and target only this one with your CSS `#foo { display: none; } a:hover + #foo { display: block} `

Answer (score 0):

When using CSS, you must always try to target only what you need to change.

In your case, you should add an ID to the div you want to hide.

```css
#hidemeonly {
    display: none;
    height:30px;
    width:290px;
    margin-left:10px;
}

a:hover + #hidemeonly {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<a><img src='https://encrypted-tbn2.google.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQB3a3aouZcIPEF0di4r9uK4c0r9FlFnCasg_P8ISk8tZytippZRQ'></a>
<div id="hidemeonly">text</div>
```

Comment: On the site it still sits as a still image and does nothing when the mouse rollsover

Comment: http://stay.safeonline.b.hscmedia.io/testing , It's all on wordpress so i'm unsure